# Show all rows even when count is null

Tags: mysql, join, mysql-8.0

I want to see all the rows from one table and then do a count on the second table to see how many match, but want to see it all even if there are 0 matches in the second table.

My query:

```
SELECT
 a.area_name,
 COUNT(b.id) AS cnt
FROM areas a
LEFT JOIN events b ON a.area_id = b.i_area
WHERE YEAR(b.i_date) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()) AND MONTH(b.i_date) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE())
GROUP BY a.area_name
```

Example desired output:

```
area 1 | 1
area 2 | 0
area 3 | 5
```

What I currently get is:

```
area 1 | 1
area 3 | 5
```

I tried CROSS and RIGHT join as well, just to make sure, but I don't get the desired effect.

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: The `ON` clause says how the tables are related; the `WHERE` is for filtering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this first: REMOVE THE `WHERE` CLAUSE

```
SELECT
 a.area_name,
 COUNT(b.id) AS cnt
FROM areas a
LEFT JOIN events b ON a.area_id = b.i_area
GROUP BY a.area_name
```

This will show `area 2`

If you really want the `WHERE` clause, move it into the `ON` Clause

```
SELECT
 a.area_name,
 COUNT(b.id) AS cnt
FROM areas a
LEFT JOIN events b ON
    a.area_id = b.i_area AND
    YEAR(b.i_date) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()) AND
    MONTH(b.i_date) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE())
GROUP BY a.area_name
```

GIVE IT A TRY !!!

Comment: Moving the `WHERE` into `ON` forces MySQL to materialize every row from the `areas` table